# An alternative proof to baby Rudin theorem 7.13

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to prove Theorem 7.13 in baby Rudin and find that my proof goes in a totally different direction than the proof in the book. I briefly sketch what I did.

> Since $f_n(x)$ is continuous, then $f_n(x)$ is bounded in compact
>   domain $K$ (theorem 4.15). Then $$M_n = \sup_{x\in E} |f_n(x)-f(x)|$$
>   is well defined and is non-increasing because $f_n(x)\ge f_{n+1}(x)
>  \ge f(x)$. Moreover, $lim_{n\to \infty}M_{n} = 0$, then from Theorem
>   7.9,  we conclude that $f_n\to f$ uniformly.

Could someone tell me whether my proof is wrong ? Or whether it is possible to prove this theorem in this way?

> **Theorem 7.13** Suppose $K$ is compact and
>   (a) $\{f_n\}$ is a sequence of continuous functions on $K$
>   (b) $\{f_n\}$ converges
>   pointwise to a continuous function on $K$
>    (c) $f_n(x) \ge
>  f_{n+1}(x)$ for all $x \in K$, $n=1,2,3,\dots$   Then $f_n \to f$
>   uniformly on $K$.
>
> **Rudin's Proof of Theorem 7.13** Put $g_n = f_n -f$. Then $g_n$ is continuous, $g_n \to 0$ pointwise, and $g_n \ge g_{n+1}$. We have to
>   prove that $g_n \to 0$ uniformly on $K$.
>
> Let $\epsilon > 0$ be given. Let $K_n$ be the set of all $x \in K$
>   with $g_n(x) \ge \epsilon$. Since $g_n$ is continuous, $K_n$ is closed
>   (Theorem 4.8) hence compact (Theorem 2.35). Since $g_n \ge g_{n+1}$ we
>   have $K_{n+1} \subset K_{n}$. Fix $x \in K$. Since $g_n(x) \to 0$, we
>   see that $x \not\in K_n$ if $n$ is sufficiently large. Thus $x \not\in
>  \bigcap K_n$. In other words, $\bigcap K_n$ is empty.Hence $K_N$ is
>   empty for some $N$ (Theorem 2.36). It follows that $0 \le g_n(x) <
>  \epsilon$ for all $x \in K$ and for all $n \ge N$. This proves the
>   theorem.

Here is also the crucial Theorem 7.9:

> **Theorem 7.9** Suppose $$\underset{n \to \infty}{\lim} f_n(x) = f(x) \quad (x \in E).$$
>
> Put $$M_n = \underset{x \in E}{\sup}|f_n(x)-f(x)|.$$ Then $f_n \to f$ uniformly on $E$ if and only if $M_n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: Please write what Theorem 7.13 is for those of us without Rudin directly on hand.

Comment: @AJY  You can find it [here](https://notendur.hi.is/vae11/%C3%9Eekking/principles_of_mathematical_analysis_walter_rudin.pdf) on page 150. The statement and proof are long.

Comment: You need to include theorem 7.9 too!

Comment: How do you conclude that $\lim_{n\to \infty}M_n=0$?

Comment: @BigbearZzz Because $f_n(x)$ converges to $f(x)$ pointwisely on $K$, so $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup |f_n(x)-f(x)| = 0$.

Comment: @kevin So what? The statement implies that $f_n\to f$ uniformly, which is what you want to prove! You cannot assume that.

Comment: @BigbearZzz Thanks. Yes. You are right, I assume too much about $\sup$ here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proof looks to be correct; the statement that $\underset{n \to \infty}{\lim} M_n = 0$ is entirely analogous to the statement in Rudin's proof of Theorem 7.13 that $g_n \to 0$ uniformly.

Just note that as @BigbearZzz points out, you should provide more justification for that particular claim, since it is the crux of the proof. But since it implies the claim from which Rudin's proof follows, once you justify it, you will be done.

**HINT:** use the uniform continuity of the $f_n$ and $f$, which follows from the compactness of $K$.

Comment: His proof as it stands now is incomplete. The most crucial point, as you've mentioned, was not justified. If I were to grade his answer I definitely wouldn't give him credit. Not yet.

Comment: I agree definitely